# how to write udate query in yii for mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, yii

```
User::model()->update($_id, array('$set' => array('d' => 1)[, array('deleted' => 1)[, array('w' => 2)]]);
```

I want to update user table with specified user id.
it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are optional parts, this stems from the PHP manual ( i.e.: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php ) so:

```
User::model()->update($_id, array('$set' => array('d' => 1)
    [, array('deleted' => 1)[, array('w' => 2)]]);
```

Will never work and will actually throw a syntax error in PHP in its current state. Instead you can try:

```
User::model()->update($_id, array('$set' => array('d' => 1)));
```